# IE7 issue with adding links in table

Tags: hyperlink, browser-compatibility

I'm having issues adding links in a table on SharePoint 2010 with IE7. I'm going to the Insert tab > Links > From Address. This is on a publishing page. Nothing happens when I do this -- and no errors are thrown into the console either. If I do this exact same thing in IE9, it works fine -- the dialog box appears to allow a link to be added to a text. If I do the same thing outside of the table, it works in IE7. Very strange.

Anyone else has experienced this? Is this a known issue? Thanks.

Comment: Whats your operating system and processor architecture ?

Comment: Windows XP and Windows 7 -- both produce the same result. Not sure what you mean by process architecture.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the IE browser?

Comment: 32-bit version on Windows XP and Windows 7.